# ios navigation bar backgroundimage

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have the following code that is supposed to set the background image on my navigation bar.

```
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] )
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"WTF");
```

It works on the iPad but not on an iPhone, on the iPhone it logs WTF ..... same result without the if statement. 
The iPhone I have is iPhone 4 running ios 6.0, the iPad is iPad 2 with ios 6.0

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the navigationController property of your view controller null when you run on iPhone? Are you using storyboard? Certain that you have embedded your VC in a navigation controller?

Comment: NavigationController is not null. I also try using the tintcolor and that works so nav controller is definitely not null. self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0f/255.0f green:73.0f/255.0f blue:73.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

Answer (score 0):

You could try this alternate old method

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation-bar-background.png"];
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Yup, always do my test against a device